# How to make users fill out their account info before making purchase woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Good day,
I would like to know if it is possible to make it mandatory for users to fill out their billing information and account details, as well as any custom endpoint we want the users to fill out before making a purchase on the website.

Taking a tailor/suit designer shop for an example;  in which measurement is important for a custom suit design. Is it possible to make a custom endpoint called MEASUREMENT required to be filled out before users can purchase a custom suit design in woocommerce?

Thanks

Comment: You can disable purchasing if customer is not logged in and if some of his data is empty - **2 ways:**  1. you can disable the add to cart functionality, or 2. you can avoid checkout. You need to choose and this requires some customization code.

Comment: How to I get or know if a users has an empty data, which code will I use to detect that? ... if ( !isset[$user->first_name] ) { disable add to cart functionality }, is that right?

Comment: When the customer data is imputed and saved it goes in `wp_usermeta` table. So to access that data and check it you will use for each `meta_key` the [WordPress function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) `get_user_meta( $user_id, 'the_meta_key', true );` where `$user_id` is the user ID and the `the_meta_key` is the key of your additional field key to be checked. To understand and make that you need a minimal knowledge.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, you're such a blessing @LoicTheAztec